# Search-Mailbox cmdlet availability with app-only authentication in Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm connecting to Exchange Online using PowerShell and the following command:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId APP_ID -CertificateFilePath CERTIFICATE_PATH -Organization ORG_NAME
```

And would like to use the "Search-Mailbox" cmdlet.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) say:

> By default, Search-Mailbox is available only in the Mailbox Search or Mailbox Import Export roles, and these roles aren't assigned to any role groups.

The app has the Exchange administrator role assigned in Azure.

In Exchange admin center, I added Exchange administrators to the Discovery Management role group that has the Mailbox Search role enabled.

After reconnecting, Search-Mailbox is still not available:

> Search-Mailbox: The term 'Search-Mailbox' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Could someone please explain why it doesn't work and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I assigned "Mailbox Search" role to the "Organization Management" role group (Exchange administrators role groups inherits from it).

Answer (score -2):

When the [CmdLet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) is not available it needs to be imported, installed or run on the correct server. It seems like `Search-Mailbox` is part of the module `ExchangePowerShell`.

I believe you either need to import the module in your PowerShell session:

```
Import-Module -Name 'ExchangePowerShell'
```

Or run the CmdLet on the Exchange server directly or use [Connect-ExchangeOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps).

Comment: The module was there, I needed to assign the missing role a bit differently (described in the own answer). Thank you for trying to help!